# Common approaches for roles and permissions in Solidity

Tags: solidity, permissions

How can I implement access control and permissioning in a Solidity smart contract, and what are some common approaches for managing roles and permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use OpenZepplin provided role based access control https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/access#AccessControl.